# Python: Error when looking for file on Mac

Tags: python, macos, file, csv, search

I have a code to search for a certain file on either Mac or Windows. While the code works on windows, it does not  work on mac at the moment

I made some changes and my code now is:

```
def find_file(root_folder, rex):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_folder):
        for f in files:
            result = rex.search(f)
            if result:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, f)
                return file_path 

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    import win32api
    def find_file_in_all_drives(file_name):
        matching_files = list()
        # create a regular expression for the file
        rex = re.compile(file_name)
        for drive in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1]:
            file_path = find_file(drive, rex)
            if file_path:
                matching_files.append(file_path)
        return matching_files

    df_location = find_file_in_all_drives("AB_NYC_2019.csv")


if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
        def find_file_in_all_drives(file_name):
            matching_files = list()
            rex = re.compile(file_name)
            file_path = find_file("/", rex)
            if file_path:
                matching_files.append(file_path)
            return matching_files

df_location = find_file_in_all_drives("AB_NYC_2019.csv")


df = pd.read_csv(df_location[0], index_col=0)
```

The error that I get now is:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

In the "windows" branch you pass a regex object as the second argument for `find_file`:

```
rex = re.compile(file_name)
...   
file_path = find_file(drive, rex)
#                             ^   regex object
```

In the "darwin" branch you pass a string, hence the error.

```
df_location = find_file("/", "AB_NYC_2019.csv")
#                               ^ a string. String objects don't have "search" method
```

Comment: Im sorry i am really new to programming whatsoever, and I am making this for a school project so my knowledge is very basic. I see what you mean, but I have no idea how I could change it to work. Could you maybe give me a suggested change? Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: I changed my code but it still does not work. Do you have any suggestions?